# Help needed with Facial Rigs

Tags: animation, rigging

I've looked all over the internet and I can't find any info on this, so I'm hoping I can get something here from you guys/gals.

I've been trying to do a good, functional, realistic facial rig, but I simply can't replicate what these people have done in these examples:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oSmgQfi6A0g

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S8xwec1Pj9k

Can someone please tell me on how I can manage to do something like that? I've tried doing it many times, but my characters facial expressions always end up looking super creepy for some reason. I just don't know what all of those bones are suppose to do or where to place them.

Can anyone explain it to me, or maybe you know of a guide/tutorial that does so?

I have compeletly run out of options here.

Here is my blend file: https://mega.nz/#!8BEFUKgQ!HJMxw4lTjZnVbbVguhnQnKhIOFazViRPuPz4X-kCUBo

Comment: It's always good to start with something simple then work your way up into more complicated things. This way it won't be overwhelming. You should share your file, else no one will be able to help with what you are doing wrong - there could be anything wrong - wrong topology, bad shapekeys, incorrectly setup constraints on bones, bad weigh paint, etc. it goes on. Too broad tutorial request are offtopic here because a video platform is better for those.

Comment: Oh Okay. When I get to my computer, I'll place one of my files here.

Comment: Okay, I've added my blend file, and that one might be one of the best facial rigs I've ever done.

Answer (score 1):

I checked your file and the culprit is weight paint. The bones are fine for basics but for good control some constraints and extra control bones should be made.

It is hard to advise about weight paint. That is quite specific to every shape and desired deformations. It is something best learned through training or experience and observing already weighted meshes (for example from open Blender movies).

Instead I am going to give steps to rig a face with Rigify addon, which makes things easier:

1. Insert a new armature, delete the bone. From *Armature properties* add the *pitchipoy.super_face* face template.

   [image]
2. Align the face template to the face mesh (scale it to size in edit-mode, not with armature scale). The bones should sit on the surface. Turn on X symmetry while editing so both sides are the same.
3. From pose or object modes generate the final rig from the template. You can delete the template armature, it has no purpose now:

   [image]
4. Bind your mesh to the generated rig with automatic vertex weights. The rig has enough control bones so it should turn out fine. If there are some issues these can be fixed by refining the vertex weights further.
5. You should now have nice controls and a rig menu with layers in tool shelf.